# Transpose of a Matrix, application in geometrie

Tags: matrices

When is the transpose of a Matrix needed in mathematics?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose#mediaviewer/File:Matrix_transpose.gif

i saw a very cool animation here, but when is the transpose needed? Any example out from computergraphics or geometry?

Answer (score 0):

The transpose matrix has to do with the dual space. If you have taken basic linear algebra courses, you should know that each matrix $A$ represents a linear transformation $\phi$ from $V$ to $W$ (where $V$ and $W$ are vectorial spaces) in respect to the respective bases $\mathbb V $ and $\mathbb W$.

The transpose of a matrix reprents the so called "dual transformation" of $\phi$, often denoted as $\phi^*$.

This is a particular linear transformation from $W^*$ to $V^*$, which are the dual spaces of $W$ and $V$. In case you didn't know, the dual space of a vectorial space $V$ is the vectorial space of linear applications $Hom(V,F)$, where F is the field in which the vectorial space is defined.

This transformation has the important property that if $w^* \in W^*$ and $v \in V$ you have that $(\phi^*w^*)(v)=w^*\phi(v)$.

Comment: allright, lets say in computergraphics you use the transformation matrix to bring a Point in space from A to B. But when would you use the transpose of the matrix?